# How do I find gas leak behind the wall or the cabinet?

Tags: drywall, tile, leak, gas, natural-gas

I know that you can buy a gas leak detector wand about $30 and you can scan to the pipe. However, if it's behind the wall or under the tile (You can't see the pipe). Is there anyway to check it before I call contractor to repair or open the wall, which is costly way to do that?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. The idea of your waiting for a response on a website before dealing with a gas leak makes me **extremely** nervous. Saving some money on drywall repairs can't be balanced against your house being destroyed in a blast, or against you or your loved ones dying in same. Please be careful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Right now, there is no leaking in my kitchen. No bad smell or anything. It just has been remodeled. I just want to double check to make sure that the contractor does the right thing.

Comment: Gas line alterations require a system leak check. The code enforcement authority witnesses the system brought to pressure with a gauge installed on the line then checks for any pressure drop over a specified time. Contractors normally perform the same check, along with soap bubble checks at all joints, prior to summoning the inspector. If the remodel received permits you should have some confidence that the line is tight. You would probably smell it if it wasn't.

Comment: I agree with @jimmy fix-it. Gas lines are normally pressure tested (in my state to 30 psi) any detectable pressure change during inspection and the job fails. Most gas lines have a pressure of 3/4 to 2 psi. If you can't smell the rotten egg smell it is probably fine.+

Comment: The very strong odorant ( mercaptan) is added to nat gas and LPG so that you do not need to guess if there is a leak. If there is a leak you can smell it ; only caution , someone must be there to smell it.